# Dynamicaly set byte[] array from a String of Ints

Tags: c#, string, int, byte, typeconverter

i usualy set my byte[] arrays like this:

```
byte[] byteArr = { 123, 234, 123, 234, 123, 123, 234 };
```

now, my problem,
i am getting the datas that have to be stored into the array as a string.

example:

```
string datas = "123, 234, 123, 234, 123, 123, 234";
```

i would like to do something like:

```
byte[] byteArr = { datas };
```

with no luck...

I tried exploding the string to array of strings, then convert each value to Int before storing into each array field. with no luck:

```
for (var i = O; i<datasArray.length; i++) {
    byteArr[i] = Int32.Parse(datasArray);  //error, cannot convert int to byte
}
```

how can i do please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple Regex to get the numbers from a string

```
string datas = "123, 234, 123, 234, 123, 123, 234";
byte[] byteArr = Regex.Matches(datas, @"\d+").Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => byte.Parse(m.Value))
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: very efficient! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about [Byte.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
for (var i = O; i<datasArray.length; i++) {
    byteArr[i] = Byte.Parse(datasArray[i]);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also [`Convert.ToByte(string val)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y57wwkzk(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string datas = "123, 234, 123, 234, 123, 123, 234";

byte[] byteArr = datas.Split(',').Select(b => Convert.ToByte(b)).ToArray();
```

Comment: i heard peoples talking about `Convert.ToByte()` reversing the values or something ? is it wrong?

Comment: @user3916429: according to msdn it just `converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer`.

Answer (score 0):

ConvertAll is very fast

```
byte[] byteArr = Array.ConvertAll(datasArray, Byte.Parse);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static byte[] CommaStringToBytes(string s)
{
  return s.Split(',').Select (t => byte.Parse (t.Trim())).ToArray ();  
}
```